# Need help understanding how to map values using markov chain

Tags: c++, maps

So Im having trouble figuring out how to create a map given an order of a markov chain and a string of text. For example, for the string "Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers." with an order of 1, the map would look like this:

| key | value(s) |
| --- | --- |
| p | e,i |
| e | t, r, d, c, d, p, r |
| t | e |
| r | *Space*,*Space*,s |
| i | p,c,c |
| p | e, i, e, i, e, p, e |
| *Space* | P, p, a, p, o, p, p |
| c | k,k,k |
| k | e, *Space*, l |
| d | *Space*,*Space* |
| a | *Space* |
| l | e |
| s | . |
| . | P |

and the with an order of 2 look like:

| key | value(s) |
| --- | --- |
| pe | t |
| et | e |
| etc. | etc. |

how would I do this in a function like `maps(string text, int order)`?

Comment: Shouldn't the `pe` key have values `t`, `r`, `c`, `p`, `r`?

Comment: Yes it is, my bad